# Matching Against Unwanted Links

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I've written a library that creates a layer of persistence by extracting href links from Wikipedia and saving them. I realized that I have a link that I'm not concerned about that's labeled as `/wiki/Cookbook:Table_of_Contents`.

What's the best way to emulate `!~` (not match) and remain Pythonic?

For better context and understanding, I would solve this problem like this in ruby:

```
if link =~ %r{^/wiki/Cookbook} && link !~ /Table_of_Contents/
```

**My Code:**

```
def fetch_links(self, proxy):
    if not self._valid_proxy(proxy):
        raise ValueError('invalid proxy address: {}'.format(proxy))
    self.browser.set_proxies({'http': proxy})
    page = self.browser.open(self.wiki_recipes)
    html = page.read()

    link_tags = SoupStrainer('a', href=True)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, parse_only=link_tags)
    recipe_regex = r'^\/wiki\/Cookbook'
    return [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all('a') if
            re.match(recipe_regex, link['href'])]
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm simply looking for a second opinion or better alternative, not a fishing rod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to exclude unwanted links.

One option would be to [pass a function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) in the `href` argument value:

```
soup.find_all('a', href=lambda x: 'Table_of_Contents' not in x)
```

This would filter out `a` tags that don't have `Table_of_Contents` inside the `href` attribute.

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <a href="/wiki/Cookbook:Table_of_Contents">cookbook</a>
    <a href="/wiki/legal_link">legal</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">google</a>
    <a href="/Table_of_Contents/">contents</a>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print [a.text for a in soup.find_all('a', href=lambda x: 'Table_of_Contents' not in x)]
```

Prints:

```
[u'legal', u'google']
```

Comment: +1 for the doc link. I never would've thought of passing the href a function, but after thinking about it as long as it returns a boolean it's legal. How did you come up with that idea?! Very clever.

Comment: @TheGrayFox yup, this is what makes this soup of tags beautiful - it is a great library. The more you get familiar with it - the more you realize that it is one of the most convenient and pleasant libraries in python to work with. And, FYI, you can pass a [compiled regex pattern](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) as an argument value as well: `soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'my_pattern_here'))`. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I'll clean it up.